# Can I create a semicircle shape in html image area map?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapping, imagemap

I need to make a semicircle shape on an image using the **Html** image **map tag**.

This is the code but it makes a circle.

```
<img src="floorplan1.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="494,686,91" shape="circle">
</map>
```

Is it possible to do this?
If yes, then please tell the way to do it.

Comment: No, this is not possible. `areas` do not support semicircles. You could make a polygon with a large number of points to *approximate* a semicircle.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shape=poly` and define each coord. Look at the example below. You can also use https://www.image-map.net/ to generate it online on your image.

In below example try clicking on the plant.

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR4C5coWnjUpQ619SpeV_MwkBj57xOa-0Jd-mLAHP2R2Ic9OY_G" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="181,257,245,246,292,201,307,135,269,76,226,53,183,55,185,151" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Comment: Yeah, but this won't make an exact semicircle.

Comment: That's true. But this is the only option. You can use online tool so that you dont have to manually find the coords.